# Writing Tee Pseudo muxer of FFMPEG by C++ code

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, mediamuxer, fluent-ffmpeg, muxer

Is there anyone who knows how to use **Tee pseudo muxer** of ffmpeg **by c++ code**. Kindly guide in doing this. 
I am working on getting multiple outputs of muxed transport stream (ts) data. I am able to mux aac and h264 in ts. But i have to get muxed ts data in multiple output.

So please guide me if anyone know how to do it with **Tee pseudo muxer**.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by myself, and i am sharing it here for others:
First do initialise AVFormatContext with tee container and output tee url like : **avformat_alloc_output_context2(&m_oc, NULL, "tee", filename);**
Here m_oc is AVFormatContext, tee is container and filename is outputs(like in filename: **"[f=mpegts]udp://127.0.0.1:2222|[f=mpegts]udp://127.0.0.1:3333|[f=mp4]output.mp4"**)

then set avformat context with this filename as:
**sprintf_s(m_oc->filename, "%s",filename);**

and go with normal muxing.c sample flow provided by ffmpeg.